# Sending visual selection to external program without affecting the buffer

Tags: vim

What I am trying to achieve is sending visual selections to external programs without affecting the contents of the buffer.

### Example

Let the following code block represent the current buffer. Let [<] represent the start of visual selection, and [>] represent the end.

```
This is not a test 1
[<]This is not[>] a test 2
This is not a test 3
This is not a test 4
```

From this I would like to send this text to external program. e.g:

```
:<some vim command>!<some shell command>
```

### The Almost Solution?

A solution that almost works is:

```
:[range]w ! cat | <some shell command>
```

This works for sending things linewise. For example:

```
:%w ! wc -l      # produces --> '4'
:2,3w ! wc -l    # produces --> '2'
:2w ! wc -w      # produces --> '6'
```

However, using the example buffer above:

```
:'<,'>w ! wc -w  # produces --> '6'
```

But I would like something that to produces '3' and does not affect the contents of the buffer.

Ideas?

Comment: If your goal is actually to count the words inside the Visual selection, know that there's a built-in command for that: select, then press `g CTRL-G`. See `:h v_g^g`.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. But I was just using wc as an example command since it has such readable output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A range is *always* linewise.

No matter what you do, every Ex command that accept a range will *always* take `'<` as the *start **line*** and `'>` as the *end **line***.

Passing a non-linewise selection to an external program is done like this:

- backup the content of a register
- yank the selection in that register
- pass the content of that register to `system()` and output the result
- restore the register

Here it is, in a function:

```
function! VisualCountWords() range
    let n = @n
    silent! normal gv"ny
    echo "Word count:" . system("echo '" . @n . "' | wc -w")
    let @n = n
    " bonus: restores the visual selection
    normal! gv
endfunction
```

that you can use in a mapping like this:

```
xnoremap <F6> :call VisualCountWords()<CR>
```

---

Also your [use of cat is useless](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html):

```
:[range]w ! cat | <some shell command>
```

should be:

```
:[range]w ! <some shell command>
```

Comment: What `gv"ny` does?

Comment: @geckos `gv` reselects the last visual selection, `"ny` yanks it to register `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select...
<esc>
:exe '!echo '.string(lh#visual#selection()).' | wc -w'
```

Seems to do the trick.

With `lh#visual#selection()` coming from [lh-vim-lib](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhVimLib#Miscellanous_functions)

Comment: Instead of `string()`, `shellescape(..., 1)` would be more appropriate.