# Send visual block to external command

Tags: vim

How do I send a visual block to an external command?

I select my block using Ctrl-q and then press `!*program_name*` but Vim sends the entire lines rather than the selected text blocks.

I'm using gVim on Windows 10.

Comment: see also http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/replace-selection-with-output-of-external-command including comments on top answer

Answer (score 4):

The Ex commands are line-based, whereas *blockwise visual mode* is a Vim extension. That explains the feature mismatch.

The [vis.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195) provides a `:B` command that allows you to send the actual selected block to an Ex command. It also works with `:!`, so you can do things like this:

```
:'<,'>B !tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
```

Comment: i spoke too soon. This plugin is closer to what I'm looking for, but I want to sort all lines within the block selection. The external sort command I'm using allows me to sort by version number (sort -V). Something similar to Vissort but with more flexibility.

Comment: If you just want to sort the selected text (and leave the stuff before and after in each line as it is), vis.vim is the solution. If you want to sort entire lines, but based on the selected column, just use `:!sort ...`, but specify the field (via `--key=...`).

Answer (score 3):

Vim always send the whole line to external commands, but you can do that using the function of the answer of romainl in this question:

[Sending visual selection to external program without affecting the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124424/sending-visual-selection-to-external-program-without-affecting-the-buffer)

> Passing a non-linewise selection to an external program is done like
>   this:
>
> - backup the content of a register
> - yank the selection in that register
> - pass the content of that register to system() and output the result
> - restore the register
>
> Here it is, in a function:
>
> ```
> function! VisualCountWords() range
>     let n = @n
>     silent! normal gv"ny
>     echo "Word count:" . system("echo '" . @n . "' | wc -w")
>     let @n = n
>     " bonus: restores the visual selection
>     normal! gv 
> endfunction
> ```
>
> that you can use in a mapping like this:
>
> `xnoremap <F6> :call VisualCountWords()<CR>`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately because of design I'm not going to be able to do what I want to do. I need the ability to sen blocks of text with the flexibility of an external command or script. Oh well.