# Nerdcommenter -- only comment out selected text

Tags: vim

In nerdcommenter for VIM, I can easy toggle a comment by doing:

- `[count]<leader>c<space>` |NERDCommenterToggle|

> Toggles the comment state of the selected line(s). If the topmost selected line is commented, all selected lines are uncommented and vice versa.

However, I find that I'll often way to only comment a visually-selected block of text, for example something like:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in nerdcommenter, or what might be a good way to do this in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `:`-commands can accept only line-range. That's in Vi/Vim design. A workaround is possible, but it could seem a bit complicated, as you can see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61736620/how-to-run-commands-against-block-wise-visual-mode-selection).

For this reason, I recently wrote a plugin [vim-opera](https://github.com/matveyt/vim-opera) which implements such trick and also simplifies making mappings. For example, in my vimrc I have

```
nnoremap <expr><silent>gc opera#mapto('Comment!')
xnoremap <expr><silent>gc opera#mapto('Comment!')
nnoremap <silent>gcc :Comment!<CR>
```

Here `:Comment` is my own "commenter", but any line-range command will do.

The whole implementation takes more than 100 lines of code, so for those interested in details, I suggest to browse the source.